# Why printing same values for signed and unsigned vars in java?

Tags: java

The below one prints values `-2147483648  and  -2147483648`

```
int a = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

int b = -a;

System.out.println( a+ "   "+b);
```

Could someone explain what the other value is not +ve? It is because of boundary issues?

Comment: Integer.MAX_VALUE equals to 2147483647 (or: 2^31-1)

Comment: High sign bit 0 is for pure positive numbers and zero. High sign bit 1 is for negative numbers, so there is one negative number more than pure positive numbers. MIN_VALUE == MAX_VALUE + 1 so to say. And -n = ~n + 1 (flip bits, add one).